# What is the difference between using tab and space when we do source code formatting?

Tags: javascript, html, css, coding-style

When we want to give some formatting to code to make it more readable. We can use both *Tab* and *Space* (by pressing space bar on keyboard). Many time I give *space* manually.

I've some confusions

- Is there any difference between them?
- Is using *tab* better than *spaces*?
- Does using *space* increase the size of document and *tab* not?
- Is there any differences between single *tab*/*space* and multiple. in terms of page size?
- Is there any difference on using *tab* or *space* in HTML, CSS and Javascript?

Dreamweaver has this option in preferences

[image]

Comment: "Is there any difference between them?" !?! [Religious] Wars have been fought over less important things! Oh, wait, wars are fought over this thing...

Comment: Each space is a character, I reckon it adds to the document size (this when dealing with multiple spaces vs one tab), appart from that it may be related to what is visually appealing.

Comment: For web development (HTML, CSS, JS), the answers to the first questions are insufficent to answer the question about page size. Don't forget to take compression (gzip) and minification (Google Closure compiler, YUI compressor, etc.) into account.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

Tabs need less characters and are formatted by users (some display as 2, some as 4 spaces), what can make some code look bad on some other environment.

Spaces consume more KBs but look equal everywhere.

Good editors have retab-functions to convert those.

In JS and CSS it does not matter, HTML *should* not matter, but can in some cases.

Comment: Tabs can be a different size on different computers and PRINTERS!

Comment: How do spaces not matter in JS and CSS when they are downloaded with the rest of the characters in the source code? That could be thousands, millions of spaces that would be cut to one quarter using tabs.

Comment: Usually there are two (not mutually exclusive) Options making this matter almost nothing: 1. Using GZIP in transfer. 2. Using compressing tools in a build toolchain.

Comment: If you watch code with tab=4 spaces, you will not get sick if you watch your friend's code who watch code with tab=2 spaces. Because your friend's code will be shown with your tab preference.

Answer (score 13):

Using tabs is annoying because some editors interpret a tab as 4 spaces, some others as 8 spaces, and some others as 2 spaces, which makes the indentation completely wrong if tabs and spaces are used in the same file.

I always use spaces only to avoid this problem.

It could slightly increase the download size of your pages, but you could also minify the JavaScript and the CSS files, and/or use gzip on-the-fly compression to mitigate this small problem.

Comment: In most editors there is a setting for how many spaces one tab equals.

Comment: Yes, but if you need to change this setting each time you switch from a file to another, because some developer like it at 8 and some other at 2, it's really annoying.

Comment: If you're concerned about download size, use compression and minification *long before* you consider saving bytes by writing your code differently. It's far more effective than crippling the code formatting on your side - both in terms of bytes saved and in terms of programmer time saved (directly by not worrying and indirectly by not being distracted by the consequences).

Comment: I disagree with the conclusion. Actually in order to avoid the problem we should use tabs **OR** spaces, but not both.

Comment: The problem with tabs only is that is doesn't allow some kinds of indentations, like for example align all the arguments of a function call on the same column.

Comment: @JBNizet When we use tabs then we should use a different indentation concept. For instance if function arguments do not fit in the main line then all argument list should start on the next line (with no argument in the main line). The main thing that I like about tabs is that they force the developer to follow indentation rules.

Comment: @JBNizet - I found this article today http://tarantsov.com/hackers-coding-style-guide/why-tabs-should-be-avoided.html which is suggesting to not to use tab

Answer (score 9):

Using Tabs :

- Tab takes less space
- Tab is user system defined :: So in my case if i prefer 2space::tab i can view it that way
- Moving one indentation level back is lot easier if you use tabs .

Using Spaces :

- Tab space ratio usually defaults to 1:8 . So on all 'newbie' systems your code will be difficult to read . Also if you view your code on github / pastebin there again it will be some what awkward .

My take : Go with tabs for development , find replace '\t' with '    ' [4 spaces] and then for release minify [ this strips tabs and spaces ] .

Answer (score 6):

Personally, I see it as an issue of preference involving ease of formatting. I'd rather use tab, because it's only one click and it simulates 4-5 spaces. A lot simpler in my mind. Otherwise, I don't see much purpose.

Answer (score 2):

In pretty much all cases, you can use tabs or spaces and it won't make a difference. Using tabs will make the source files slightly smaller, while using spaces will ensure that spacing is consistent for everyone (since tabs can have a variable width).

I believe the only language where it actually matters is Python. For any other language, tabs vs. spaces is basically even - just be sure to pick one and be consistent with it.

Answer (score 2):

Using a tab technically takes up less memory than using, say, 5 spaces.  So when trying to optimize file size it could be helpful.  However minifying text would have a better effect. Look up minifying code for more on this topic.

Some people prefer spaces and some prefer tabs.  Its a matter of preference and many folks have different reasons for it.  Here is a great article on this point: http://www.jwz.org/doc/tabs-vs-spaces.html

Chances are for your application it wont matter much.

Answer (score 2):

If your code is being downloaded, such as HTML or Javascript or CSS, it makes a difference because the file is larger if spaces are used. How much larger depends on the number of lines and indent levels. It's the same as including comments in the code: they do increase file size.

If your code will be compiled, such as Actionscript or Java or C, or tokenized such as Perl, it makes no difference whether you use spaces or tabs, and you can include as many paragraphs of comments/documentation as you like, because it's only for your own benefit. All those tabs and spaces and comments will be ignored when the final, lower-level code is built.

Answer (score 0):

I think a good mix would be to use tabs for indentation since they are easier to handle and customize, and spaces for line continuation, since they are uniform. This would provide a good mix of readibility, space usage and customization.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).